# FFMPEG - Merge two video files into one

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have converted two different format videos into TS format by using FFMPEG and now I am trying to merge them into one video. I have used following two commands but the output file only shows the first video.

1. ffmpeg -i "concat:1.ts|2.ts" -c copy -qscale:v 2 output.mp4
2. ffmpeg -i "concat:1.ts|2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -qscale:v 2 output.mp4

`1.ts` video does not have audio.